# Doob's decomposition of a brownian motion.

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $B_n$ be a discrete Brownian motion.
I need to find the Doob decomposition for ($B_n^2$).
Can someone help me please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Davide Girudo, can you give me any hints, i am totally stuck on what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, the Doob decomposition of a (discrete) $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable process $(X_n)_n$ is of the form

$$X_n = X_0 + M_n+A_n \tag{1}$$

where $(M_n)_n$ is a martingale and $(A_n)_n$ an increasing (predictable) process. If we take the conditional expectation with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ we get

$$\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = X_0 + M_{n-1} + \mathbb{E}(A_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = X_0 + M_{n-1} + A_n$$

where we used in the first step that $(M_n)_n$ is a martingale and in the second step that $(A_n)_n$ is predictable. Now if we substract $X_{n-1}$ on both sides, we find from $(1)$ that

$$\mathbb{E}(X_n - X_{n-1} \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = A_n-A_{n-1}$$

or, equivalently,

$$A_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}(X_j-X_{j-1} \mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}). \tag{2}$$

---

In the given example we consider $X_n := B_n^2$ where $B$ is a Brownian motion. In order to find the Doob decomposition, we have to calculate $(2)$, i.e.

$$A_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}(B_j^2-B_{j-1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}).$$

To this end, write

$$B_j^2 - B_{j-1}^2 = \big( (B_j-B_{j-1})+B_{j-1} \big)^2 - B_{j-1}^2$$

and use that $B$ has independent increments as well as $B_n \sim N(0,n)$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help saz really appreciated :)

Comment: hey @saz i have tried to solve the last part. But i am still a bit lost dont know exactly what to do. Here is my try. \begin{align*}
A_n &= \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}(B_j^2-B_{j-1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1})\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\big[\big( (B_j-B_{j-1})+B_{j-1} \big)^2 - B_{j-1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}\big]\\
&=  \sum_{j=1}^n \bigg[\mathbb{E}\big[\big( (B_j-B_{j-1})+B_{j-1} \big)^2\mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}\big]-\mathbb{E}[ B_{j-1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}\big]\bigg] \\&= \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\big[ (B_j-B_{j-1})^2\mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}\big]
\end{align*}

Comment: @ChristianSkjøth Use that the Brownian motion has independent increments.

Comment: I cant see it. It is the square that annoys me. is this $\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\big[ (B_j-B_{j-1})\mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}\big] \mathbb{E}\big[ (B_j-B_{j-1})\mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}\big]$ a legal operation? @saz

Comment: @ChristianSkjøth No, it isn't. If $X$ is independent of a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, then what is $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$?

Comment: @ChristianSkjøth Exactly. So, as $B_j-B_{j-1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{j-1}$.....

Comment: but i still have the square. but can i do this then. $\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\big[ (B_j-B_{j-1})^2\big]$

Comment: @ChristianSkjøth Yes, you can. If $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}$, then $f(X)$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}$ for any (measurable) function $f$, Here $f(x) =x^2$.

Comment: Ty @saz your help is really appreciated. Can i reduce it more, if so i dont know because of the ^2 part

Comment: @ChristianSkjøth Use that $B$ has stationary increments, i.e. $B_t-B_s \sim B_{t-s}$. Moreover, note that $B_t \sim N(0,t)$ and therefore $\mathbb{E}(B_t^2)= t$.

Answer (score 0):

@saz last question :) Can you confirm this \begin{align*}
A_n &= \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}(B_j^2-B_{j-1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1})\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\big[\big( (B_j-B_{j-1})+B_{j-1} \big)^2 - B_{j-1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}\big]\\
&=  \sum_{j=1}^n \bigg[\mathbb{E}\big[\big( (B_j-B_{j-1})+B_{j-1} \big)^2\mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}\big]-\mathbb{E}[ B_{j-1}^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}\big]\bigg] \\ &= \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\big[ (B_j-B_{j-1})^2\mid \mathcal{F}_{j-1}\big] \\ &=  \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\big[ (B_j-B_{j-1})^2\big] \\ &=  \sum_{j=1}^n  \mathbb{E}[ (B_j)^2] -\mathbb{E}[ (B_{j-1})^2] \\ &= \sum_{j=1}^n n-n \\ &= 0
\end{align*}